# How to get timezone in a shorter format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, activesupport

`Time.zone.name` gives  `"Eastern Time (US & Canada)"`. Is there a way to get the time zone for a Time object in a  shorter format like `EST`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails use tzinfo gem https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html)
, but the shortcode you are looking for is not provided. So there's no direct way to get it. Although the Time class does have a method called `zone` which returns the shortcode for a time of a given time zone.
So I would do something like this if I was in your place:

```
(Time.new.in_time_zone current_user.time_zone).zone
(Time.new.in_time_zone "Eastern Time (US & Canada)").zone
```

Comment: Tried it but it keeps giving me `LMT` instead of `EST` etc

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I have updated the code. And this time, have checked it myself before suggesting. :)

Answer (score 2):

I was curious about this answer as well, so I searched around and found a pretty neat answer here: https://makandracards.com/makandra/67330-why-you-can-t-use-timezone-codes-like-pst-or-bst-for-time-objects

It explains the potential shortcomings of rails TimeWithZones objects but gives the following answer:

```
def human_timezone(time_string, timezone)
  time = time_string.in_time_zone(timezone)

  if time.zone.match?(/^\w/)
    time.zone
  else
    time.formatted_offset
  end
end

>> human_timezone('2019-03-28 16:00', 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)')
=> "PDT"
>> human_timezone('2019-03-28 16:00', 'Berlin')
=> "CET"
>> human_timezone('2019-05-01 16:00', 'Almaty')
=> "+06:00"
```